# How to fetch result from MySQL row with multiple same-name columns with PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
select * from A left join B on A.columnc=B.columnd
```

results returned by above SQL will include both columns of A and B.

And what if A and B have some columns with the same name?

How to retrieve the value from PHP?

Comment: You'd get an error stating ambiguous columns - the database can't tell which of the two columns with identical names to use.

Comment: @rexem: That is not true. The SQL is absolutely correct, the error would happen if the query was explicitly selecting a column name that exists in both table, but not specifying the table prefix.

Answer (score 18):

You probably want to be more explicit in your query. That way you can provide aliases for your columns:

```
SELECT
  A.foo as a_foo,
  B.foo as b_foo
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.columnc = B.columnd
```

Comment: If you only need a few columns from your second table, you can (in mysql, anyway) do something like "SELECT a.*, b.column_that_also_exist_in_a as someAliase ..."

Comment: @tim: Should be able to do this in any ANSI-compliant database system.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is actualy in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

"If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the last column will take precedence. To access the other column(s) of the same name, you either need to access the result with numeric indices by using `mysql_fetch_row()` or add alias names. See the example at the `mysql_fetch_array()`  description about aliases. "

Especialy `mysql_fetch_array()` seems to be the best candidate when you insist on using star in the select statement:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)
```

Then you can refer to the unambigous fields by `$row[name]` and to the ambigous one by `$row[col_number]`, but that limits portability of your code (maybe next version of MySQL is going to return columns in a different order?). Recommended solution is to rewrite your query and list all the required fields instead of using star and for the ambigous ones - use aliases.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [column aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_alias.asp) in the select statement.

Answer (score 2):

In Java+MySQL from the ResultSet object, you can use for example getString("a.id") and also getString("b.id"), if your query was like "SELECT a.id, b.id FROM a,b"

I dunno if there is something like this in PHP.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful to somebody: Because I was using some templating, I couldn't easily use aliases each time, and I wanted the associative array for ease of use. 
CREDIT PILCROW for his answer on [how to mysql_fetch_array on joined tables, but columns have same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851261/how-to-mysql-fetch-array-on-joined-tables-but-columns-have-same-name/12851315#12851315), but in MySQLi:

```
$qualified_names = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields($result); ++$i) {
    $fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i);
    $table = $fieldinfo->table;
    $field = $fieldinfo->name;
    $qualified_names["$table.$field"]="$table.$field";
}
$newrow = array_combine($qualified_names, mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM));
```