# how to mysql_fetch_array on joined tables, but columns have same name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fetch result from MySQL row with multiple same-name columns with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416980/how-to-fetch-result-from-mysql-row-with-multiple-same-name-columns-with-php)

I have two tables, and they share similar column names.

Query is:

```
SELECT a.name,b.name
FROM tablea a 
JOIN tableb b ON a.id = b.id
```

Results are put into an array:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
   $aname = $row['name'];
}
```

Once I added in that second table I noticed the `$aname` was using tableb's data.

**Question**(s): How can I store both `name` columns, `$row['a.name']` does not work. My guess is maybe I need to alias each result in the query. Any suggestions? *Should I same avoid giving the column names in the future*?

---

`I know mysql_* is deprecated. Save your energy.`

Comment: Hey, did you know that mysql_* is deprecated? Sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: No i have not seen any red boxes and don't know you're talking about

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your guess was right. You need to create an `ALIAS` for the columns so you can fetch it uniquely,

```
SELECT a.name Name1, b.name Name2
FROM tablea a 
JOIN tableb b ON a.id = b.id
```

then you can now call

```
$row['Name1']
```

Comment: I didn't know you could alias without using `AS`

Comment: That's what I thought... so there is no way to use the table alias instead?

Comment: @JohnWoo Thanks for your help! I actually noticed this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416980/how-to-fetch-result-from-mysql-row-with-multiple-same-name-columns-with-php?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

There is a way.

[`mysql_field_table()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-table.php) will tell you a result set field's name given the `$result` handle and ordinal position.  In conjunction with [`mysql_field_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php), that should be everything you need:

```
// Fetch the table name and then the field name
$qualified_names = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); ++$i) {
    $table = mysql_field_table($result, $i);
    $field = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
    array_push($qualified_names, "$table.$field");
}
```

You could wrap this into your own `mysql_fetch_qualified_array` function, for example, to give you an associative array keyed on `"table.field"`:

```
function mysql_fetch_qualified_array($result) {
  ...
  // caching $qualified_names is left as an exercise for the reader
  ...
  if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $row = array_combine($qualified_names, $row);      
  }
  return $row;
}
```